# how to launch Gear 2 notifications app from my own Tizen app

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I would like to add a shortcut to default Samsung notifications app on my Tizen app.

I've found that the name of the app (which I want to launch) is : com.samsung.wnotification2

I used the following code to launch it:

```
tizen.application.launch("com.samsung.wnotification2",onListInstalledApps);
```

But it doesn't work.

Here arethe privileges I used :
privileges I installed:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.setting"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.info"/>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is correct ID of application?
Add:

```
tizen.application.launch("com.samsung.wnotification2",onListInstalledApps,function(e){console.log(e);});
```

you will get:

- NotFoundError - If the application is not found with the specified
  ID.
- InvalidValuesError - If any of the input parameters contain an
  invalid value.
- UnknownError - If any other error occurs.

your permissions are ok - otherwise you would get SecurityError

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
```

Instead of

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.info"/>
```

Also it's better to provide a custom (empty) success function, not onListInstalledApps that is most probably has a different purpose.